# Search bar with coredata

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I'm developing an application that needs a search bar and I'm new to the concept but since my application runs with Core Data, how does the concept of search works? if someone could give me an explanation I would be very thankful.

Best Regards.

Comment: There's no difference with core data and other techniques like a plist. Just run a predicate search on an array of objects and return the results.

Comment: Look at this http://snipplr.com/view/33653/

Answer (score 0):

It the same like use regular search (I think I never use search bar without core data) aside from some methods that you need use fetchResult instead of array or something..

first:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.searchResults = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:[[self.fetchResultsController fetchedObjects] count]];

     NSError *error = nil;
    if (![[self fetchResultsController]performFetch:&error])
    {
        NSLog(@"error!!! %@",error);
        abort();
    }

    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

second:

```
- (void)filterContentForSearchText:(NSString*)searchText scope:(NSString*)scope
{
    //if([self searchResults]){
        [[self searchResults]removeAllObjects];
    //}


    for (Books *book in [self.fetchResultsController fetchedObjects])
    {
            if([self searchResults])
            {
                NSComparisonResult result = [book.title compare:searchText
                                                   options:(NSCaseInsensitiveSearch|NSDiacriticInsensitiveSearch)
                                                     range:NSMakeRange(0, [searchText length])];
                if (result == NSOrderedSame && [self searchResults])
                {
                        [self.searchResults addObject:book];
                }
            }
    }
}
```

other methods should stay like regular search, I think.
you can use this tutorial http://timroadley.com/2012/03/05/core-data-basics-part-7-search-bars/ and also look at my git hub project I use story board, core data and search bar at this project https://github.com/dennis87/bookList good luck.